# Configuration/Dependency using multiple file application in FastAPI

Tags: python, configuration, dependencies, singleton, fastapi

I am trying to figure out how to make configuration/singleton available to different module.  Perhaps there is a standard Python way of doing this that I don't know yet.  So I create a configuration singleton that has all the app configurations and want to 'share' this with all modules.  Same use-case would apply to sharing DB connection.

**main.py**

```
app = FastApi()
config = some_config_object_from_somewhere()

app.include_router(
        collection.router,
        prefix='/api/collection'
    )
```

**api/collection.py**

```
router = APIRouter()
@router.post("/", status_code=201)
async def collect():
    # I want to use config that is created/defined in main.py
    # HOW?  I thought dependency injection that is built into FastAPI would
    # help, but can't seem to define something in a different module and have it
    # available in the 'router' module
```

Comment: I 'solved' my present situation by having main initialize a singleton that is defined in a separate module.  Other modules can then import this singleton and have access to the application level settings/db/config.  Python not being my native tongue, I feel I am mumbling a bit.

Comment: if you solved your issue, please submit your complete answer and accept it.

Answer (score 2):

In general, about project structure, the basic structure of a FastAPI application is the the same as a Flask one, see [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/):

> It’s time to start coding! Create the flaskr directory and add the `__init__.py` file. The `__init__.py` serves double duty: it will contain the application factory, and it tells Python that the flaskr directory should be treated as a package

FastAPI (and also Flask and other functional-style framework) defines database access in terms of functions using sessions, see [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#crud-utils).

Below on that documentation page:

```py
# Dependency
def get_db():
    try:
        db = SessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):  # <<< injected here
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_email(db, email=user.email)
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email already registered")
    return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)
```

Comment: Yes, on the right track, but that exposes my problem or my complete lack of understanding.  If get_db() is defined in a module(say main.py) and then I want to use in a different module (api/collection.py), how do I do that.  I wanted to structure my app so that routes are defined in a separate module from the module defining app.  Said in a different way, I want the database dependency in my routes defined in a different module.  main creates the concrete database from config, and then I want routes to use the configured database function/object

Comment: see my edit. Briefly, you need to define a factory (or your application object) in `__init__.py` so every module can access it. Then you can define your code in any module you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

According to @tiangolo (the creator of FastAPI):

> "You can declare the same dependency at the router or decorator level
> and then declare it again in the path operation to get its value.
>
> It won't be evaluated twice, it doesn't add any extra computation,
> there's a dependency cache in place that stores the values of already
> solved dependencies for a given request
>
> https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/424#issuecomment-584169213

So for the case of sharing a DB connection, you would simply need to re-import `get_db` and re-declare it in the router file.

For the case of sharing configuration data, however, the [FastAPI documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/) states that dependencies are for "shared logic", sharing "database connections", and enforcing "security, authentication, role requirements"—which seems different than shared data.

Putting your configuration data into its own module does the job (doesn't need to be implemented as a singleton) and is officially Pythonic:

> The canonical way to share information across modules within a single
> program is to create a special module (often called config or cfg).
> Just import the config module in all modules of your application; the
> module then becomes available as a global name. Because there is only
> one instance of each module, any changes made to the module object get
> reflected everywhere.
>
> https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

(The Singleton pattern is arguably [less Pythonic](https://python-patterns.guide/gang-of-four/singleton/).)